# How do I filter/fix nmap NSE http-enum?

Tags: nmap, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

I am running various nmap scripts against my servers and the `http-enum` often flags directories like

```
/css/
/error/
/images/
/js/
/xml/
```

If I try to navigate to the IP + folder my browser times out. Yet somehow nmap is reaching these folders.

How can I resolve these issues so the folders are truly protected/nmap no longer shows them in the scan?